# Как найти значение, возле которого было максимальное кол-во соседей со значением примерно равным исходному значению?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, оптимизация

Есть DataFrame [по ссылке](https://dropmefiles.com/DCO5h).

Есть в DataFrame колонка `close` и необходимо найти значение/я по данной колонке возле которой было наиболее максимальное кол-во соседей (значений примерно равных исходному значению).

**Пример**: цена 1.17632 возле которой были обнаружены соседи (значения в пределах +/- 0.0005) в кол-ве 13 штук

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

PS саму идею сделал, но думаю не совсем корреткно её выполнил:

```
def find_protorgovok(name_df, delta: float):
    """"поиск сильных проторговок, name_df - имя dataframe, в ко-м будем 
    искать проторговки, delta - параметр погрешность
    в пунктах для поиска соседей рядом"""
    df = name_df[["time", 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']]
    df_open = df[['open']].round(5)
    df_close = df[['close']].round(5)
    df_low = df[['low']].round(5)
    df_high = df[['high']].round(5)

    # delta = 0.0005  # погрешность в пунктах

    a_massiv = np.array([])  # создаем пустой массив
    # near_values = []
    counts_values = []  # список где будут хранится все значения ока-ся рядом(соседи)

    # цикл по столбцу "df_close" from df_list сверху/вниз
    for i in trange(len(df_close)):  
        # value = df.iloc[i][df.columns[j]]            # get value_df; i - номер строки, j - номер столбца
        value = df_close.iloc[i][df_close.columns[0]]  # get value from df_close
        #  print(i, value)
        a_massiv = np.append(a_massiv, value)  # добавляем каждое новое value from df_column в массив array
        minElement = np.amin(a_massiv)  # находим min- элемент массива [a_massiv] с добавленными элементами
        #  print(f"a_massiv: {a_massiv}")
        #  print(f"minElement: {minElement}")

        # ---- start my_function --
        distance_high = minElement + delta  # значение рядом (сверху) со минимльным значением
        distance_low = minElement - delta  # значение рядом (снизу) со минимльным значением

        # df_list = [df_close, df_low, df_high]        # список столбцов нашего df для iterate for columns from df_list
        #  near_values = []                            # create empty list

        if distance_low < value < distance_high:  # если значение value находится рядом с нашим minimum of a_massiv
            #  print(f"номер строки i: {i}, from: {df_close.columns[0]}")  # df_item.columns[0] - str(имя колонки)
            b = value
            #  print(f"найден сосед рядом b: {b}, min= {minElement}")
            #    near_values.append(b)
            counts_values.append(minElement)  # добавляем нужные значения в список counts_values
        time.sleep(0.1)

    # print(f"near_values: {len(near_values)}")
    # print(f"counts_values: {counts_values}, len counts_values: {len(counts_values)}")
    b_list = []  # создаем пустой массив для цены
    d_list = []  # создаем пустой массив для кол-ва появлений
    # поиск максимально встречющегося элемента в списке counts_values - содержащем все значения которые были рядом
    for i in range(len(df_close)):  # проверка счетчика появлений значения до 45 - раз
        new_list = [e for e in set(counts_values) if counts_values.count(e) == i]
        if new_list:
            if i > 3 and len(new_list) == 1:  # выводим только если появления более > 3 раз
                b_list.append(i)
                d_list.append(new_list[0])
                print(f"price : {new_list[0]}, кол-во появлений: {i}")  # [1, 3]
    dict_df = dict(zip(d_list, b_list))
    # print(f"dict : {dict_df}")
    df = pd.DataFrame(dict_df.items(), columns=['Цена', 'кол-во_появлений'])
    print(f"df : \n{df}")
    return df
```

Comment: вот как то так /

Comment: дайте пожалуйста определение соседа - по какому критерию записи считаются соседними?

Comment: сосед - значение которое равноудалено сверху/снизу на значение delta = 0.005. Допустим значение 1.17632 и все значения в пределах +/- 0.005 от исходного будут являться соседями

Comment: т.е. сосед может быть в любом месте выборки? Критерием соседства считается только значение?

Comment: пока не появится новое исходное значение возле которого тоже не обнаружилось достаточно большое кол-во соседей. Допустим возле цены 1.17632 обнаружено 13 соседей, возле цены 1.1820 обнаружено 8 соседей.

Comment: По-моему вам нужно скользящее окно `rolling` с какой-то кастомной функцией. Но надо ещё думать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие задачи:

```
def count_close_points(x, ser, delta=0.005):
    return ((x - delta <= ser) & (ser <= x + delta)).sum()

delta = 0.0005
d = {x: count_close_points(x, df["close"], delta) for x in df["close"].unique()}
val = max(d, key=d.get)
cnt = d[val]
print(f'Value [{val}] has [{cnt}] "neighbours"')
```

вывод:

```
Value [1.17761] has [42] "neighbours"
```

Comment: Спасибо .... завтра посмотрю я спать устал очень !     : )

Comment: если нужно найти только значение, то можно попробовать так: `max(df.close, key=lambda x: sum((x-delta)<=i<=(x+delta) for i in df.close))`